# Multiple entries in crystal reportviewer after adding a SQL expression field

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, field

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I installed the latest crystal reportviewer (22)
What I want is to click a button and create a report from the customer that is selected in the datagridview and the addresses that are shown in the second datagridview.
I managed to do all that but the problem is that a few fields contain numbers which need to be converted to text. An SQL query I would use to do this would be like:

```
SELECT c.customer_nr, c.status, s.rename FROM CUSTOMERS c INNER JOIN SETUP s on s.id = c.status WHERE s.afk = 'STA'
```

In my SETUP database I have the columns ID,AFK and RENAME so if the status would be 1 it would convert to text: "ACTIVE", if status = 2 it would convert to "INACTIVE" for example.
I could do something with a formula field like this:

```
IF ({c.status} = 1) THEN "ACTIVE" ELSE
IF ({c.status}) = 2 THEN "INACTIVE"
```

but that is not good because i could add another status or change the name in the database etc.

So then I tried with an SQL expression field and I put something like this:

```
(
SELECT "SETUP"."RENAME" FROM SETUP
WHERE "SETUP"."AFK" = 'STA' AND "SETUP"."ID" = "CUSTOMERS"."STATUS"
)
```

There must be something wrong because I get the correct conversion but there is only one address in the database but I get 7 pages all with the same address. There should only be one address like I get when I remove the SQL expression field. Where does it go wrong?

*** EDIT ***
I found the problem. When I create a new database that contains only unique id's then it works. In my original database I have multiple times the id's 1,2,3,4,5 but with different abbreviations in column AFK. Somehow the query looks for the id value and every time it finds this id no matter the AFK value it generates an entry for the address value.
Maybe in the future I will find out how this exactly works for now I have a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table for example CrRepSta and add the following entries:

```
ID,AFK,RENAME
1,STA,Active
2,STA,Inactive
etc
```

The new query:

```
(
SELECT "CrRepSta"."RENAME" FROM CrRepSta
WHERE "CrRepSta"."AFK" = 'STA' AND "CrRepSta"."ID" = "CUSTOMERS"."STATUS"
)
```

And by the way the statement "CrRepSta"."AFK" = 'STA' is not really needed.